# Listing all processes information using c

Tags: c, process, linux-kernel

I want to list all running processes with pid,ppid,comm and size.I have this following code working except for the ppid and size,so how this can be done.

--code --

```
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include "sched.h"
#include "sched1.h"


/* This function is called when the module t is loaded. */
 int process_init(void)   
 {
   printk(KERN_INFO "lOADING  MODULE \n");
   printk(KERN_INFO "PID \t PPID \t PNAME \t SIZE \n");

  struct task_struct *task;
  for_each_process(task)
  {
    printk(KERN_INFO "%d \t %d\t %s \t %d \n",   task->pid,task->ppid,task->comm,task->sz);
   }

        return 0;
  }
```

Comment: would `execlp("ps","ps","-ef",(char *)NULL);` work for your purposes

Comment: instead of which line ?

Comment: @ishyfishy His use of `printk` implies that this is running inside the kernel, not in a user process. He can't call `execlp` from the kernel.

Comment: Can you give us your kernel version ? I cannot find ppid and sz members in [struct task_struct](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h#L1389)

Comment: the same here ,so because of this I asked how to get the parent id and the size of the process .

Answer (score 1):

The parent pid and total vm size is not directly encoded in the `task_struct`, you need to call `task_ppid_nr` to get the parent pid, and use `task_struct->mm` to get the process's vm size.

Try following:

```
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include "sched.h"
#include "sched1.h"
int process_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "lOADING  MODULE \n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "PID \t PPID \t PNAME \t SIZE \n");
    struct task_struct *task;
    struct mm_struct *mm;
    for_each_process(task)
    {
        mm = get_task_mm(task);
        printk(KERN_INFO "%d \t %d\t %s \t %d \n",
                task->pid, task_ppid_nr(task), task->comm, mm->total_vm);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. nothing prevents task from being freed 2. mm can be null 3. if it was not null, the reference is leaked 4. ->comm requires the task to be locked

Comment: @employeeofthemonth glad you bring it up, feel free to edit the answer.